# C# downloading email attachment - not as Single File Web Page

Tags: c#, email, outlook, attachment

I have following code to download email attachment which is in .xls format.

```
Application app = new Application();
        NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        string recipientName = "aaa.bbb@ccccccc.xx";

        Recipient recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
        recip.Resolve();

        if (recip.Resolved)
        {
            MAPIFolder inboxFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Items items = (Items)inboxFolder.Items;
            items = items.Restrict("[Unread] = true");

            foreach (MailItem eMail in items)
            {
                string Subject = eMail.Subject;

                if (Subject == "xxxxxxxxx")
                {

                    if (eMail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= eMail.Attachments.Count; i++)
                        {
                            eMail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(@"C:\TestFileSave\" + eMail.Attachments[i].FileName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to open xls file, it shows message that the file is in different file format than specified by the file extension.

And I saw that the attachment is downloaded as Single File Web page, is there any trick to save it in real .xls format?

Comment: So what format is eMail.Attachments[i] in the email ? Is it truly a binary XLS file? Is it an MHT?

Comment: had this same issue and I decided to download `OpenXML` to resolve that issue.. it would be in the `DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll`

Comment: @Alex K, it is .xls file, when I downloaded it manually, I have no issues with file format.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE do you have any example code, which method to use?

Comment: Let me check my project where I have used it ..give me a few minutes to check

Comment: @Alek K. You were write, it IS in mht format. But I opened it and read its content as Excel woorkbook, programatically in C#, so, in the end it was not that big problem, I read the content I needed.